# How to access the Canvas on Widget Blueprint in UE5 Graph

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I am new to UE5. Trying to work out some UI. I have created a Widget Blueprint (HUD) on which I have placed a canvas (TheCanvas), on which I have placed a text:

[image: HUD - Canvas - Text]

Now I am trying to access the canvas (TheCanvas) in the Graph / node editor of the Widget Blueprint (HUD). I need this for some programming logic, such as e.g. getting a list of all the children on the canvas etc.

I have seen on screenshots that people can access this canvas, however I am unable to get a reference to it. When I type Canvas in the filter, it does not show up.

I thought I need to make TheCanvas a variable of the HUD, but I cannot find a way to do that either. There is no Promote to variable context menu, and no Expose checkbox on the details of the Canvas.

Being new to this, the concepts are not clear for me. Please can you advise what I am doing wrong? I need to programmatically access TheCanvas in the Graph/node editor of the HUD.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Someone showed me the `Is Variable` checkbox on top of the Details panel. I was looking for it down in the properties box

[image]